# Hugging Face Transformers trainer: per_device_train_batch_size vs auto_find_batch_size

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

A [Hugging Face Transformers `Trainer`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments.per_device_train_batch_size) can receive a `per_device_train_batch_size` argument, or an `auto_find_batch_size` argument.

However, they seem to have different effects. One thing to consider is that `per_device_train_batch_size` defaults to 8: it is always set, and you can't disable it.

I have also observed that if I run into OOM errors, lowering `per_device_train_batch_size` can solve the issue, but `auto_find_batch_size` doesn't solve the problem. This is quite counter-intuitive, since it should find a batch size that is small enough (I can do it manually).

So: **what does `auto_find_batch_size` do**, exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`auto_find_batch_size`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments.auto_find_batch_size) argument is an optional argument which can be used **in addition** to the `per_device_train_batch_size` argument.

As you point out, lowering the batch size is one way to resolve out-of-memory errors. The `auto_find_batch_size` argument automates the lowering process. Enabling this, will use [`find_executable_batch_size` from `accelerate`](https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/usage_guides/memory#findexecutablebatchsize), which:

> operates with exponential decay, decreasing the batch size in half after each failed run

The `per_device_train_batch_size` is used as the initial batch size to start off with. So if you use the default of `8`, it starts training with a batch size of `8` (on a single device), & if it fails, it will restart the training procedure with a batch size of `4`.

Comment: Thanks! However, when training, the `Instantaneous batch size per device` is always reported to be the chosen `per_device_train_batch_size`, even when `auto_find_batch_size` is enabled. This seems to contradict the explanation...

Comment: @AldanCreo There was a [recent bug fix](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/23800) which logs the correct batch size when `auto_find_batch size` is specified. If your issue is solely related to logging, but you observe that the training procedure is able to execute without out-of-memory errors, then you can ignore this and/or upgrade your `transformers` library accordingly.

Comment: Oh, that explains everything! Thanks a lot for the clarification :)